# No applicable method for 'lookup_defaults' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a set of animal and human observations by their recorded time.
The DF looks like this:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJBq.png)

I have like 20k entries between November '20 and February '21 and need them filtered by day and night events. Those day and night events would be something like 8pm - 6am (night) and 6am - 8pm (day).

I am using the `filter_time` package and my code looks like this:

```
Observation_clean$date_recorded <- as.POSIXct((Observation_clean$date_recorded), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
Observation_clean_time <- as_tibble(Observation_clean)
Observation_clean_time1 <- as_tbl_time(Observation_clean_time, index = "date_recorded")


Observation_clean_night <-  filter_time(Observation_clean_time1, '2020-11-04 20:00:00' ~ '2021-02-05 06:00:00')
```

As soon as I run the last line, it'll give me this error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `{ ... }`.
x no applicable method for 'lookup_defaults' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Unfortunately I don't understand what to do here. Perhaps the entire approach isn't that good? If someone could help, it'd appreciate that.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but maybe it will help

with `data.table` package filtering is really easy

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

Observation_clean <- Observation_clean %>% as.data.table()

Observation_clean_night <- Observation_clean[between(hour(date_recorded ), 6, 19) & # hours 
                                               between(as.Date(date_recorded ), as.Date("2020-11-04"), as.Date("2021-02-05")) # dates
]

Observation_clean_day <- Observation_clean[!between(hour(date_recorded ), 6, 19) & # hours 
                                             between(as.Date(date_recorded ), as.Date("2020-11-04"), as.Date("2021-02-05")) # dates
]
```

Comment: That did do exactly the trick I needed. Thank you.